# Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'

Tags: visual-studio, qt5

Ранее, создавая проект **QT** в *Visual Studio*, я мог запустить *qmake* в папке проекта и всё работало отлично. Однако сейчас, при запуске, *qmake* выдаёт следующие:

> Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Output:
> ===================
> ===================
> Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?

В *Visual Studio* стоит расширение **QT VS Tools**, в настройках которого *msvc2019_64*.

Answer (score 0):

Обновление **QT** до новой версии решило данную проблему. Также в самой среде нужно было нажать: *расширения* - *Qt Vs Tools* - *Open Qt Project File*.